# Intellij IDEA formatting XML with aligning attributes

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea

Is there any chance to format XML files, and some code like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:longClickable="false"
    >
```

to be like this?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width  = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:orientation   = "horizontal"
    android:longClickable = "false"
    >
```

[image]

---

I've tried the space around "=" option, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately this is not possible. I've always thought that this is something that would be useful. Your question prompted me to opened a feature request for it: [IDEA-117587: XML - Align attribute values](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117587)  Please consider voting for it.

Comment: thanks, in PhpStorm we have this option for css and php array and javascript array...

Answer (score -1):

you can try [xml editor](http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/), not sure if it can satisfy what you want, but i think you'd like it for its various features.

Answer (score -1):

Try DefinitionEqualizer. It is old but still seems to work.
http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1701?pr=idea

Update: Note that this only seems to work on the first "=" on the line and in your case it actually appears to delete the line!